# AJAX return data fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use AJAX to insert data into my table, once this is done however I want my new value to fade in, inplace of the existing .html data.

I have the following only it doesnt seem to fade in...

```
// UPDATE INCOME 
     $("#salary-upd").on("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var elem = $(this);
          $.post("update_salary.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                $(".spends").fadeIn().html(data);
     });
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ What in the world does "it doesnt seem to fade in " *mean*?  Your example also has a syntax error.

Comment: Put the fadeIn after the thml

Comment: Are you making sure it's faded out first by setting its opacity to 0?  Looks like that could be the issue.

Comment: It doesnt fade in, it just instanly appears over the current value @asawyer

Comment: @Liam Is jQuery animation turned off?

Comment: No @asawyer, all my other animations work, Ive got it working to some extent, the initial value now dissapears instantly and the new one fades in

Comment: What is `.spends`? table class? Are you replacing the entire table content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
   $(".spends").fadeOut('slow', function() { 
      $(this).html(data).fadeIn('slow'); 
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
  $(".spends").append(data).fadeIn();
```

Comment: try adding a delay like $('selector').fadeIn('slow') or instead 'slow' use a number

Comment: @Liam I think you want to append data, not replace it, try `append()` instead of `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  Set the initial value to start, then do the animation explicitly:

```
$(".spends").css('opacity', 0).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
```

Comment: Sort of works @dbaseman, the initial value disappears instantly now but the new value fades in

Comment: @Liam Try `$(".spends").animate({'opacity': 0}, 'slow', function() {  $(this).html(data).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 'slow'); })`